# MariaDB rotated logs are empty on CentOS7

Tags: mariadb, logs, centos

I've been having the same problem for a couple of weeks now. I have the following `/etc/logrotate.d/mariadb` file configuration:

```
/var/log/mariadb/*.log {
        create 600 mysql mysql
        notifempty
        weekly
        rotate 12
        missingok
        delaycompress
    postrotate
        # just if mariadbd is really running
        if test -x /usr/bin/mysqladmin && \
           /usr/bin/mysqladmin ping &>/dev/null
        then
           env HOME=/root/ /usr/bin/mysqladmin --local flush-error-log \
              flush-engine-log flush-general-log flush-slow-log
        fi
    endscript
}
```

I also made the /root/.my.cnf file with permission 400 and contents:

```
[mysqladmin]
password = <secret>
user= root
```

It rotates the log just to a new log file but when I check the new logs no errors are logged and I had to flush the logs manually every week. And if I run `sudo logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/mariadb` the logs rotate just fine and new logs can be seen on the new log files. But if I let cron handle it weekly, the problem occurs.

Any idea on how to fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: If you need `env HOME` for the mysqladmin flush* commands you'd also need it on the `mysqladmin ping`. Your shell may have this already set. Maybe cron/logrotate doesn't. Its also possible that a global logrotate doesn't include the selinux permission to access /root/.my.cnf. Try putting credentials in non-globally readable `/etc/my.cnf.d/mysqladmin.cnf` file.

Comment: Will give this one a try, I just also noticed that if I set it too weekly then the problem would persist, but if I set it to daily then no problem occurs.

Comment: see [this recent answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/300029/mariadb-hidden-disk-usage-for-log-dir/300042#300042), its has the same effect that the compressed files are empty. So its purely that your `.my.cnf` isn't read. This is honestly one reason that unix_socket auth permission on the root user are very useful, then its logs are rotatable and there's no password in a file that can leave access available. See also [pr1556](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/pull/1556) (that I need to review again).

Comment: Please provide `ls -l` before and after the rotate script runs.

Comment: `-rw-------. 1 mysql mysql    619980 Oct 20 08:23 mariadb-err.log
-rw-------. 1 mysql mysql   3357147 Oct 19 07:12 mariadb-err.log-20211017`

After running `sudo logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/mariadb`

I get 

`-rw-------. 1 mysql mysql        79 Oct 20 08:24 mariadb-err.log
-rw-------. 1 mysql mysql    619980 Oct 20 08:23 mariadb-err.log.1
-rw-------. 1 mysql mysql   3357147 Oct 19 07:12 mariadb-err.log-20211017`